# How to programmatically install private .apk?

Tags: android, installation, apk, android-fileprovider

I have managed to download a `.apk` file I uploaded to an AWS S3 bucket using `DownloadManager`, but I can't install the package with out user confirmation. I am working in a private dedicated device app that manages the device owner-level stuff. In this case, I have provisioned my device with `adb shell set-device-owner`.
I have been looking all over the place and I have figured out some parts of how to achieve the installation.

I'm working with Android 8.1 and our devices won't be upgraded to a newer Android version.

My Manifest file has the provider

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

as well as the permission
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES>`

My `provider_paths.xml` file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

and the code that executes the installation is in a separate class `InstallationUtils.java` with a public static method `installPackage` that gets called from a button in the main activity.

```
public static boolean installPackage(Context context) {
    File toInstall = new File(context.getFilesDir(), appName+".apk");
    
    if (!toInstall.exists()) {
        Log.e("installPackage", "File does not exist!");
        // Handle case
        return false;
    }

    if (!toInstall.canRead()) {
        Log.e("installPackage", "File can't be read!");
        // Handle case
        return fasle;
    }


    Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", toInstall);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

Some parts of the code like the directories are hard-coded because I am trying to make it work first before using best practices.
I have also tried using `<external-path>` and `<external-files-path>` as well as having a copy of my APK on all these directories (or at least what I believe are the correct directories, I am fairly new to Android development).

The closest I have gotten to installing the package was being able to open the installer activity, but it says "Unknown" in the action bar, and "Staging app..." in the middle of the Activity. This activity immediately stops with a dialog that says: "There was a problem parsing the package" with only the option to press "OK", which goes back to the main activity of the DPC app.

I also saw other alternatives using `PackageInstaller`, but I don't quite understand them.

---

Code for downloading APK from S3 bucket

The way I downloaded my .apk file was getting a pre-signed URL from AWS S3.

public static long downloadApkFromS3(
Context context,
String fileName,
String downloadUrl,
Handler updateHandler) {

```
    DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(downloadUrl);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);

    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(getFilesDir().toString(), fileName + ".apk");
    request.setMimeType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");

    long downloadId = downloadManager.enqueue(request);

    // Run task in background thread to check download progress later
    executor.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int progress = 0;
            boolean isDownloadFinished = false;
            while (!isDownloadFinished) {
                try {
                    Log.i("Thread", "Sleeping");
                    Thread.sleep(1000); // Check every second.
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
               
                Cursor cursor = downloadManager
                        .query(new DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById(downloadId));
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    int downloadStatus = cursor
                            .getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));
                   
                    switch (downloadStatus) {
                        case DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING:
                            long totalBytes = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES));
                            if (totalBytes > 0) {
                                long downloadedBytes = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));
                                progress = (int) (downloadedBytes * 100 / totalBytes);
                            }
                            break;

                        case DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL:
                            progress = 100;
                            isDownloadFinished = true;

                            // Release executor
                            executor.shutdown();

                            // Release handler
                            updateHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                           

                            break;

                        case DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED:
                            break;
                        case DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING:
                            break;
                        case DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED:
                            isDownloadFinished = true;
                            break;
                    }
                    Message message = Message.obtain();
                    message.what = UPDATE_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS;
                    message.arg1 = progress;

                    updateHandler.sendMessage(message);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    return downloadId;
}
```

This code gets called from the main activity with with the lines

```
Handler updateHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper(), new Handler.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(@NonNull Message message) {
        if (message.what == UPDATE_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS) {
            int downloadProgress = message.arg1;                           
            // Update progress bar
            mProgressBar.setProgress(downloadProgress);
            mProgressPercentage.setText(Integer.toString(downloadProgress) + " %");
        }
        return true;
        }
    });
InstallationUtils.downloadApkFromUrl(this, "testDownloadFile", downloadUrl, updateHandler);
```

where `downloadUrl` is the presigned URL from the S3 bucket and `updateHandler` is just for updating the UI when the download is running.

Comment: What is your question,?

Comment: How can I successfully install the already downloaded APK or what is the problem with the code above that does not let me install the APK? The code I showed above gives the result I described at the end of the post where the installation gets stuck with a "There was a problem parsing the package" dialog.

Comment: `intent.setData(apkUri)` You should also set Type.

Comment: And you did not tell how you downloaded the file or where to. Its hard to see what you are doing

Comment: Also use toInstall.exists() and toInstall.canRead() before launching intent.

Comment: I downloaded it from a AWS S3 bucket I own, and tried several different places in the device. I have copies of the APK I am trying to install in `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` and `context.getFilesDir()`, to see if I could get it to work somewhere, but I couldn't. I have no preference to the place I put the files since this is a dedicated device, so it is fully managed. Do you have any recommendations for the best place to download my .APK to?

Comment: Is the type "application/vnd.android.package-archive" correct if I am sure I will uniquely download .APK files?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244143/discussion-between-the-bosco-and-blackapps).

Comment: Yes, that is the type. And has nothing to do with downloading but with your ACTION_VIEW intent for installing.

Comment: You still did not tell how you downloaded . But ala.. Please update your code with all the things i suggested.

Comment: I added the suggestions and the code that explains how the APK is downloaded

Comment: `request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(context.getFilesDir().toString()... ` That can never work. You cannot use getFilesDir() there. You should give one public directory name. Not a full path. The file will not be downloaded at all and .exists() will return false.

Comment: `as well as having a copy of my APK on all these directories ` Dont do that as you and i will not know what happens. Only act like actual code.

Comment: `but I can't install the package with out user confirmation.` No. Ofcourse not. But is that a question?

Comment: I have not had any problem downloading to any directory I want, that's why I have tried using copies in different directories to see if any of them work. I've tried many of them, but I can't install them. Can I download the app to internal storage and install it from there? (and then delete the .apk file). 
This is a dedicated device (corporate-owned single-use if you want). That is why I provisioned it in the first place with `adb`, so I didn't have to ask the user for permission to download or install files, but this is definitely possible according to Android's website.

Comment: `request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(context.getFilesDir().toString()` ?

Comment: Just `getFilesDir().toString()` is the one that works. I just fixed it in the question

Comment: No. That cannot work. I said that before.

Comment: Well I don't have an answer as to why it is working and downloading the file. I can execute the installation manually as well.